# How do you move a NSImageView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode4.5

I have this situation:

I have a NSView which contains a custom NSImageView.
I'm trying to move the NSImageView from the view controller, but no success so far.

This is the header of the view controller:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#include "MyAppDragAndDropImageView.h"

@interface MyAppViewController : NSViewController <MyAppDragAndDropImageViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet MyAppDragAndDropImageView *dragAndDropImageView;

@property (nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *workingFileLabel;
@property (nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *workingFileSizeLabel;

@property (nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet NSButton *clearButton;

-(IBAction)onClearButtonClicked:(id)sender;
```

All IBOutlets have been connected from the Interface Builder.

I'm using this code inside the view controller to move the custom NSImageView...

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    //dragAndDropImageView frame
    NSRect ddivFrame = [dragAndDropImageView frame];
    ddivFrame.origin.x = SOME_NUMBER;
    ddivFrame.origin.y = SOME_NUMBER;

    [dragAndDropImageView setFrame:ddivFrame];
    [dragAndDropImageView setNeedsDisplay:YES];

}
```

...But nothing happens!

Using NSLog I've found that the frame "x" and "y" have been updated, but it is displayed in the old position! Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: Are you creating and assigning `dragAndDropImageView` in the code? If so, please edit your question to include that code. Also, you haven't overridden either `frame` or `setFrame:` in your `MyAppDragAndDropImageView` class, right?

Comment: It's assigned using the Interface Builder and I haven't overridden those methods. But I found a temporary solution (look at the answer).

Comment: I'd hesitate to call it a solution without first understanding the problem. Incidentally, why are you setting the frame from `awakeFromNib`?

Comment: `dragAndDropImageView` and `clearButton` are centered inside the view. In `awakeFromNib` I set them offscreen, and then I use a NSAnimation to slide them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `dragAndDropImageView` and `clearButton` are centered inside the view. In `awakeFromNib` I set them offscreen, and then I use a NSAnimation to slide them in.

Why not set them as hidden/`alphaValue` to `0` in the nib, and then have your NSViewAnimation both show them (fade them in) and move them into position?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    //dragAndDropImageView frame
    NSRect ddivFrame = [dragAndDropImageView frame];
    ddivFrame.origin.x = SOME_NUMBER;
    ddivFrame.origin.y = SOME_NUMBER;

    [[dragAndDropImageView animator] setFrame:ddivFrame];

}
```

This works flawlessy!